# How to make the onLocationResult function work?I

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show my current location and store the location to Firebase and to place a marker on my current location.

i searched in google and even stack overflow t couldn't find anything related to my problem.
Also i read googles documentation on its maps sdk but didn't understand it.

```
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() { //NEW onLocation changed
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                mLastLocation = location;

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));//1-21



            }
        }

    };
```

I expect to see a blue dot in my app but instead only see the map without any markers or even without my current location

Comment: have you add any marker to map?

Comment: you aren't drawing any markers, you are simply moving the camera.

Comment: checkout my answer, hope it helps you out

Comment: @a_local_nobody the problem i faced was that onLocationResult was not being called i have added the marker in such a way that its called after a button is pressed

Comment: i see, did you manage to make it work @AdwaithKv?

Comment: no sir it still not being called -_-

Comment: @a_local_nobody sir do have any other suggetion.

Comment: are you running this on an emulator or on a device ?

Comment: Running it on my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public fun placeMarkerOnMap(location: LatLng, drawableResInt: Int? = null): Marker? {
    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(location)
    val marker = googleMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)

    if (drawableResInt != null) {
        marker?.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawableResInt))
    }

    return marker
}
```

Your code miss the part of adding marker.You can add marker to particular LatLng with/without custom image.Then only, move the camera.

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Marker By doing following

```
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude());
LatLng latlng= new LatLng(latitude, longitude); ////your lat lng
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posisiabsen, 65);
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```